# How to download latest file from remote repository using shell script?

Tags: shell, wget

I have a remote repository which stores release builds. What I want to do is to write a shell script to download the latest build(a .zip file). The repository web page looks like this:

```
1.0.0
  |---> 1.0.0.zip(link)

1.0.1
  |---> 1.0.1.zip(link)

1.0.2
  |---> 1.0.2.zip(link)
```

1.0.x is a directory, where a zip file resides in. There will be more than one or no build released everyday. Basically I want to construct a URL like

http://path/to/file/1.0.x.zip

With x being automatically aware of latest number on the web page, so that wget would be easy to use.

Comment: how do you know x? or if you dont know x you would have to test every plausible x number to get what you want (not very efficient)

Comment: Consider an FTP server for this, you can list files in the directory and automatically choose the latest one by checking modification time or simply by listing them alphanumerically and taking the last one. - BTW the command to list files over FTP is simply `ls` so it's not that hard to do something like `ls | sort | tail -n1`. If you want, for instance, 1.0.x releases just `grep` first like this: `ls | grep '1\.0\..*\.zip' | sort | tail -n1`.

Comment: This is also possible over HTTP but you'll need to store a list of zip files and their location somewhere on the web server, if you have that it's a piece of cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# base path to server
base="http://path/to/file/"
# get files contained in base dir
lynx -dump -listonly "${base}" | grep http | grep '1\.0\.[0-9]+\.zip' | awk '{print $2}' > .tmpfiles
# get latest version number (x)
version=$(awk -F'.' '{ print $3 }' .tmpfiles | sort | tail -n1)
# get filename of latest build
latest=$(grep "1.0.${version}" .tmpfiles)
# download latest file
wget -qO - "${base}${latest}" > .tmp.zip && unzip .tmp.zip
```

You could easily modify this so that you can pass the version number as a parameter to the script.

But it would be a lot easier if the builds were stored on an FTP server then you can create a simple FTP script.

Comment: Thanks, got what I wanted.